# Redirection on direct access to PHP script

Tags: php

I'm building a website that contains a considerable amount of object-oriented PHP code. To keep the code clean, each class is stored in a single file named `[classname].class.php` and `require_once`'d in the script file. Being a form evaluation script, it already has redirections based on the POST variable to prevent dummy execution and database errors.

How do I make it so anyone trying to access the `.class.php` files gets redirected to the related HTML page, but keep it usable by `include` and `require`?

Comment: put it outside of your publicly accessible folder

Comment: I had that in mind, however due to organisation I would like a PHP solution, not a server workaround.

Comment: "server workaround" or just the best approach?

Comment: i wouldn't call putting it in a folder outside your public folder a workaround. I'd call it a best practice. I'd call your desired php solution the workaround

Comment: I guess it is. I'll just stick with that then. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can either

- put it outside the public_html folder
- deny access/redirect using filename patterns in the .htaccess
- build a small php code in (the top of every class file) that looks for a variable which is initialised in the index.  If it's not there, redirect.

If you need further explanation on any of these, just ask.

Comment: Thanks! It seems my original way is the worst option, though, given the useless processing power spent.